# Geoserver style external label

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sld

I have uploaded PostGIS/PostgreSQL tables to GeoServer and now need to create SLD style to draw points with a name of locations.

The problem is that point coordinates are in one table, and the name of the location is in another.

There is a common column in both tables, in form of PK>FK. I couldn't find a solution for taking, let say, an external label in SLD. I can't merge this two tables into one and would like to avoid using views in the database for that.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to create join in Geoserver. In such cases you need to use view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a view in the database that joins the two tables (`create view myjoin as select ....`) or, if you don't have the necessary rights, build a [sql-view](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) in GeoServer to do the same

Comment: Views in a database isn't an option because in some other things they can make things slower than they should be. Will have to look more at this sql-view, didn't know about it.